# Splunk - Get Prefefined Outputs Based on the event count and event data

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a query as below. The result is always predefined as -

1. If the query result has 3 events and if the 3rd event has event="delivered" as value then the whole transaction needs to be returned as "COMPLETE".
2. If the 3rd event is present and event!="delivered" then the status becomes "PENDING"
3. If the 3rd event is not present at all, then the transaction is marked as ERROR

My Query -

```
index=myindex OR index=myindex2 uuid=98as786-ffe6-4de1-929y-080e99bc2e6r (status="202") OR (TransactionStatus="PUBLISHED") | append [search index=myindex2 (logMessage="Producer created new event") event="delivered" OR event="processed" serviceName="abc" [search index=myindex uuid=98as786-ffe6-4de1-929y-080e99bc2e6r AND status="SUCCESS" AND serviceName="abc" | top limit=1 headerId | fields + headerId | rename headerId as message_id]]
```

Result events -

Event1 - 202 Accepted

Event 2 - Adapter Success

Event 3 - delivered or error or processed

My high level dashboard should look like below -

Complete - 6378638

Pending - 2173

Error - 6356

The unique ID will be the UUID on which the count to be performed. 
What can be the possible way we can do this - eval ? Lookup ? not sure as I am new to splunk.
Please let me know if more information is needed if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps.  The terminology in your question is a little inconsistent so you may need to adjust the field names in this query.

```
index=myindex OR index=myindex2 uuid=98as786-ffe6-4de1-929y-080e99bc2e6r ((status="202") OR (TransactionStatus="PUBLISHED")) OR (index=myindex2 (logMessage="Producer created new event") event="delivered" OR event="processed" serviceName="abc") (index=myindex uuid=98as786-ffe6-4de1-929y-080e99bc2e6r AND status="SUCCESS" AND serviceName="abc" )
| stats count, latest(event) as event by headerId
| eval result=case(count=3 AND event="delivered", "COMPLETE", count=3 AND event!="delivered", "PENDING", count!=3, "ERROR", 1=1, "UNKNOWN")
| stats count by result
| table result count
```